# My Laptop is too slow and I don't know if this is a software problem or hardware problem. Please read for explanation of the issues

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, hardware

My Laptop is a Thinkpad T420 with intel i5 dual core and 4GB RAM. I have installed on Linux ubuntu 16.04 and windows 7 in dual boot, however I work only with ubuntu.

There are some problems: when I open chrome browser and Firefox with a five or six pages I notice a very incredible slow work of entire computer. 
Windows open very slowly, writing on browser, note, open office word is very hard because the computer work absolutely slowly and sometimes freeze or stop.

Why? I don't know if this may is a hardware problem (is i5 dual core good for?) or a software problem. How i can check it?

How can I solve this issues?

Thank you for your patience and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `free -h` and `top` .. just edit it into the question above, and format appropriately.

Comment: to add: also `htop` can be useful as a alternate to `top`. "i5 dual core" is good enough. Ubuntu does not often increase minimum hardware requirements. Question: FF and Chrome with each 1 tab open does that work well? If so your issue is with the 2 browsers. Interested in testing with another browser? Midori, Opera, Vivaldi?